# Terraform get module path from inside module

Tags: terraform

I'm creating AWS resources using terraform modules.

I'd like to tag those resources with the name/path, & if possible the version, of the module that created them.

Only problem is that because modules are downloaded into the main, I can't seem to get the originating path.

Module lives at git::https://domain/project/_git/module name

Code of module in test:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "mybucket"{
....

tags = {
  tfmodule = path.module
}
}
```

But this just produces :
".terraform/modules/mybucket"

Does anyone have ideas for to get the originating path without hard coding?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are calling the "module path" is actually the module's source, in your case that is a Git URI. A [module source](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources) value can be many things, such as a local path, or a Git repository URI, or a Terraform Registry URI. There is no a variable in Terraform to reference that value in your code.

The `path.module` variable is always going to be the path where the module is installed locally. In [the documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/references) you can see this is a Filesystem reference, not a module source reference. This value is useful when you need to reference non-Terraform files from within the module.

If you want to use the module's source location as a tag value, you would probably have to pass that into the module as an input variable. For example you could declare an input in your module:

```
variable "module_tag" {
  type = string
}
```

And then in your parent, or root module you would do this:

```
module "my_module" {
  source     = "git::https://domain/project/_git/module_name"
  module_tag = "git::https://domain/project/_git/module_name"
}
```

And finally, back in your module, you would set the tag:

```
tags = {
  tfmodule = input.module_tag
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as I feared then  Just have to trust the developers (including myself) to update both in sync.